# how to manage transaction in business logic layer

Tags: hibernate, struts, business-logic

I want to know how to manage transaction in business logic layer(BLL).

I've searched this site to find the answer to my question but didn't success.

I want to use hibernate and struts in my web application.

In Actions of struts, I call the BLL functions.

In BLL function, I want like this :

```
Begin transaction
try {
    Call DAL to do something
    ...
    Call DAL to do something
    Commit Transaction
catch {
    Roleback Transaction
}
```

In DAL, I use hibernate functions to do an action.

But I cannot find out how to manage the transaction at BLL.

Please give any advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most common practice is to add transaction management, along with the connection management, as an aspect. If you are using Spring, it might be as simple as annotating corresponding methods of your services (your business logic is contained in services, right?) as @Transactional.

Comment: My BLL contants many services. I found this article http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Java/Managing-Transactions-with-Hibernate/3/ . But I wonder if there is any risk if i do as this post. I've never read about spring before. So, do I flow this post or spring ?

Comment: This article is outdated, and contains very bad code. Use Spring, Guice, EJB3 or any other framework allowing you to handle transactions declaratively (i.e. with annotations, for examples). Else, your code will be cluttered with transaction management, and will probably contain more bugs.

Comment: My eyes! My eyes! Well, I guess after looking at all that code one can really appreciate the elegance of using Spring (or any other DI/AOP framework for that matter) annotation @Transactional.